# Rails - .htaccess not forcing users to use https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I want user to only be able to access the https version of the site. I figured out that a way to do this is with a .htaccess file. I've have added the SSL cert and thats all working fine.

I made the .htaccess file and added the following code in it (replacing 'example' with the domain name)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I deployed it and visited http://example.com/ and it loaded just fine as http.

I dont know if because its a rails app that I might need to put the .htaccess file in the public folder, or if there is more I need to do. But from what I read this should work.

I'm using google cloud platform to host my site, and I cant find the VM server type so maybe its not the right server type to run .htaccess files on?

I'm hoping someone here knows how to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.htaccess` try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

However, with Rails you can use the following in your environment config:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```